# can't insert index of an spitted array to a variable

Tags: python

I am having hard time figuring out the issue of insert from list after splinting to a variable

here's the file im reading from

```
John:Yoko:1966

Brad:Anjolina:2005

Boonie:Clyde:1930

Clyde:Boonie:1930

Hillary:Bill:1971

Yoko:Jhon:1966
```

this is the function

```
def mismatched(file_name):
    d={}
    for line in open(file_name):
       line=line.rsplit()
       two_couple=line.split(':')
       couple1=two_couple[0]
       couple2=two_couple[1]

       print(two_couple)
       #print(couple2)
```

the error
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/omer/Desktop/pythonProjects/2016S1M1.py", line 28, in 
    main()
  File "C:/Users/omer/Desktop/pythonProjects/2016S1M1.py", line 21, in main
    mismatched('airports.txt')
  File "C:/Users/omer/Desktop/pythonProjects/2016S1M1.py", line 13, in mismatched
    two_couple=line.split(':')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: You reassigned `line` to be the results of `line.rsplit()`.  Therefore `line` is a list, and lists do not have a `split()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Line is already a list you can't apply split function to a list, try this:

```
def mismatched(file_name):
    d={}
    for line in open(file_name):
       two_couple=line.rsplit()
       couple1=two_couple[0]
       couple2=two_couple[1]

       print(two_couple)
       #print(couple2)
```